# What is the idiomatic way to assign one value to a slice in Rust?

Tags: rust, slice

I would like to assign a value to a slice `a[start..end]` (suppose `a: &mut Vec<usize>`), and of course a traditional `for` can meet this requirement:

```rust
for i in start..end {
    a[i] = value;
}
```

I also tried `a[start..end].copy_from_slice(&vec![value; end - start])`, but clearly it is much slower.

I would like to know whether there is an idiomatic way to do so in Rust.

Comment: I would say it is pretty much a personal choice. A simple loop looks good enough.

Answer (score 10):

Starting with 1.50, you can use [`slice::fill`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.fill) on a subslice:

```rust
a[start..end].fill(value);
```

Comment: Oh, nice indeed!

Comment: Cool! According to my benchmark, it is even faster than the `for`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `iterator` trait to modify it:

```rust
a[start..end].iter_mut().for_each(|v| *v = value);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b74ac2e03c7167d2910cb08ba7d5d20)